# Finite union sigma field

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm really struggling to grasp why $\sigma$-fields are **not** necessarily closed under finite union.

If the above statement is true then;

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P) $ be our probability space such that $(A,B \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow A \cup B \not\in \mathcal{F})$.

Surely $P(A \cup B) $ then cannot be evaluated.

Any advice on how I could move forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It was my mistake. My friend was saying a ring isn't necessarily a sigma-ring, and I got the statement confused. Lesson learnt; if a statement doesn't make sense, check first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigma field definition include closure under countable union which implies closure under finite union.

Let $A_1 = A$, $A_2=B$, $A_i = \emptyset, i \geq 3$

$$\bigcup A_i = A \cup B$$

Hence $P(A \cup B)$ can be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I think your definition is simply incorrect. $\sigma$-fields *are* closed under countable unions by definition (and hence finite unions as well). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Definition.